# Do wounds ever completely heal in adventure mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

Do wounds ever completely heal in Dwarf Fortress adventure mode? My adventurers seem hampered by yellow wounds that never heal.

Is there some way to speed or encourage these wounds to heal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the wound does not heal by fast travelling, the wound will never heal in adventure mode.

For some wounds, this isn't a big deal (broken fingers, ex.), bruises and chippings will always heal, it's the "torn tendon/ligament" and shattered or fractured bones that are most worrisome.

Note that scarring will turn the part of the body brown, permanently, but has no other ill-effects.